# How to conditionally change values of a column in R?

Tags: r

```
lat         long      class
42.19028    -70.94528  c
42.19028    -72.94528  c
42.19028    -76.94528  b 
42.19028    -77.94528  c
42.19028    -77.94528  c
42.19028    -77.94528  a
42.19028    -77.94528  c
42.19028    -77.94528  d
```

I would like to rename every value of Class to c(West) and c(East) depending on whether long is greater than or less than 75. **BUT THIS MUST ONLY BE CHANGED FOR CLASS=c. Example if Class=b or d, leave it as it is.**

```
df$class[df$lon>-75] <- "c(west)"
df$class[df$lon<-75] <- "c(east)"
```

But it's not working. Could you please help?

Error message:

> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$lon > -75, value =
>   c(NA_integer_,  :   invalid factor level, NA generated

This is probably because the factor level doesn't exist. But I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df$class <- as.character(df$class)
df$class[df$class == "c"] <- ifelse(
  df$long[df$class=="c"] > (-75),
  "c(west)",
  "c(east)"
)
##
```

Comment: I so apologize. I wrongly diagnosed the problem and entered some new info in the question. It will only have to rename specific rows. Could you please be kind enough to check the question again?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `stringsAsFactors=F` while using `read.table`.  If `class` is character class.

```
df$class <- c("c(east)", "c(west)")[(df$long>-75) +1]
```

If df$class is `factor` variable

```
  levels(df$class) <- c("c(west)", "c(east)")
  df$class <- c("c(east)", "c(west)")[(df$long>-75)+1]
```

#### Update

Using the new dataset:

```
  df <- read.table(text="lat    long     class
         42.19028    -70.94528  c
         42.19028    -72.94528  c
         42.19028    -76.94528  b 
         42.19028    -77.94528  c
         42.19028    -77.94528  c
         42.19028    -77.94528  a
         42.19028    -77.94528  c
         42.19028    -77.94528  d",sep="",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=F) ####

   df$class[df$class=="c"] <- c("c(east)", "c(west)")[(df$long[df$class=="c"] > -75)+1]
   df$class
   #[1] "c(west)" "c(west)" "b"       "c(east)" "c(east)" "a"       "c(east)"
   #[8] "d"
```

Comment: I so apologize. I wrongly diagnosed the problem and entered some new info in the question. It will only have to rename specific rows. Could you please be kind enough to check the question again?

Answer (score 1):

By column name:

```
df$class <- as.character(df$class)
df[ df$class == "c" & df$long < -75 , 'class' ] <- "c(east)"
df[ df$class == "c" & df$long > -75 , 'class' ] <- "c(west)"
```

by  column number:

```
df[ df$class == "c" & df$long < -75 , 3] <- "c(east)"
df[ df$class == "c" & df$long > -75 , 3] <- "c(west)"
```

Comment: I so apologize. I wrongly diagnosed the problem and entered some new info in the question. It will only have to rename specific rows. Could you please be kind enough to check the question again?

Comment: 1.-Yes is true that `==` you can evaluate factors, but in that case you have to add the  **"c(east)"** and **"c(west)"** to the factors in that column. 2: Yes you are right and is more clean, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
dat <- transform(dat, class = ifelse(class != "c", 
                                     as.character(class), 
                                     c("c(east)", "c(west)")[(long > -75) + 1]))
#        lat      long   class
# 1 42.19028 -70.94528 c(west)
# 2 42.19028 -72.94528 c(west)
# 3 42.19028 -76.94528       b
# 4 42.19028 -77.94528 c(east)
# 5 42.19028 -77.94528 c(east)
# 6 42.19028 -77.94528       a
# 7 42.19028 -77.94528 c(east)
# 8 42.19028 -77.94528       d
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.